# global/common font size for mobile devices

Tags: css, html, cordova

I am doing mobile application using phonegap. it is for cross platform. Everything fine in this application. The only issue is font size.I gave font size as 12px in my body style. it working fine in small devices.

But when i open in ipad and tab (bigger device) 12px in too small for viewers. So is there any way to resize the font size depend on device width ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The topic to search for is CSS media queries.

```
@media screen and min-width: 768px {
    body { font-size: 20pt; }
    }
```